# Git returns "fatal: Unable to find remote helper 'https'"

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push a file from Git to GitHub. Any suggestions how should I proceed? First I received info attached in the JPG file. Afterwards, Git repeatedly returns *fatal: Unable to find remote helper 'https'* to my attempts to push the file. Sorry if I'm being repetitive but answers which I've red so far on StackOverflow didn't seem to provide a solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQHwe.jpg)

Comment: What OS are you on? What version of git are you using?

Comment: Did  you try the commands suggested in the image?

Comment: I'm on Windows and Git 2.7.0. I tried both `git config --global push.default matching` and `git config --global push.default simple` but it didn't help me to push the file to GitHub.

Comment: @Zane Did you add and commit, first, before doing the `git push -u origin master`?

Comment: when I entered `git push --set upstream origin master` Git responded 'error: src refspec origin does not match any' and `error: failed to push some refs to 'upstream'`

Comment: Ok, tried started again with `git init` and Git responded `Reinitialized existing Git repository in [direcotry on my computer]`

Comment: Then I created once more the file which I want to push. To my `git push` Git responded `fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.` Then once again I perfomed `git push --set upstream origin master` and received the same response as earlier.